# How can I use Factory Girl to generate 'dummy images'?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I want to generate a ton of dummy data - part of that data is images of various sizes. From avatars to banners to other image sizes in between.

How do I go about doing that dynamically, in my Rails 3 app, if not with Factory Girl?

Thanks.

P.S. It would also be great if that method can handle pushing the images to S3. As in, my app is configured to use CarrierWave & Fog to push images to S3. So whatever I use for dynamic image generation just needs to work with that.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do this with [RMagick](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/), a Ruby front-end to ImageMagick. I imagine you could just create a simple class that takes your width/height parameters and generates something like a rectangle with a red x running from corner to corner. It's fairly well documented, so this should be pretty easy to do.

I haven't used CarrierWave, so I can't offer advice there. If you can just feed it a file path, you should have no trouble if you include a public method to return the dummy file path.